# Integrating factor as some function of $x+y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me ow to solve the following question?

Under what circumstances will the differential equation $$M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0$$have the integrating factor that is  function of the sum $z=x+y$ ?

What I could do was that $(\mu$ is the integrating factor)

$$\frac{1}{\mu}\left(N\frac{\delta\mu}{\delta x}-M\frac{\delta\mu}{\delta y}\right)=\frac{\delta M}{\delta y}-\frac{\delta N}{\delta x}$$ . Please help me proceed..

EDIT:

I found $$\frac{f^{'}(x+y)}{f(x+y)}(N-M)=\frac{\delta M}{\delta y}-\frac{\delta N}{\delta x}$$How to solve further?

Comment: If $\mu=f(x+y)$, then what is $\partial\mu\over\partial x$? and what is $\partial\mu\over\partial y$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin : I have updated my work but still am stuck

Comment: I don't see how $\frac{\delta M}{\delta y}-\frac{\delta N}{\delta x}$ mutated into $\frac{\delta M}{\delta x}-\frac{\delta N}{\delta y}$. Other than that, it's fairly simple. Leave $f'\over f$ on the left and move everything else to the right. Now the LHS is a function of $x+y$; so must be the RHS.

Comment: @IvanNeretin :Sorry for the typo. But I wanted something particularly in terms of $f(x+y)$ only. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you want.

Comment: @IvanNeretin : Okay I think I get it. The LHS without $N-M$ is a function of $(x+y)$. But I was asking ,is the last equation further integrable?

Comment: Looks like this is not your initial question. However, if we know M and N, then we know the RHS, that is, we know $f'\over f$. That's a pretty simple ODE.

Comment: @IvanNeretin : Let me put it this way.. I am seeking a general solution, or at least a procedure to do so; and I am stuck at the fact that there are partial derivatives involved in the equation.

Comment: Solution for what? You want a condition on M and N? Yes, it is going to include partial derivatives; we can't help that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin : Can you tell me if there is a way to integrate the RHS with respect to $d(x+y)$ ?

Comment: If you know M and N: yes. If you want it in general form, with unknown M and N: I don't think so.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thank you. I got my answer. Please consider upvoting if you liked my question.